# ServiceBus AppFabricLabs DLL

Tags: appfabric, servicebus, appfabric-beta-2, servicemodelex

There are two DLL's with multiple namespaces that I am having problems with:

Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels - V2.0.50727
Microsoft.ServiceBus - V2.0.50727

I'm attempting to enhance Juval's Lowry's Service Bus Explorer to switch between:
appfabric.azure.com - production
portal.appfabriclabs.com - beta

If I only use Channels - I lose the TransportClientEndpointBehavior class, if I add both references I can't build because the ServiceBusEnvironment class exists in both DLL's in the same namespace.

I have a feeling that I'm missing something obvious here....

With both files referenced:
Error   1   The type 'Microsoft.ServiceBus.ServiceBusEnvironment' exists in both 'c:\Program Files\Windows Azure AppFabric SDK\V2.0\Assemblies\Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.dll' and 'c:\Program Files\Windows Azure AppFabric SDK\V1.0\Assemblies\NET4.0\Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll'    C:\Users\rreukema\Downloads\Idesign_WCFDisk\AprilIDesignCD\Demos\ServiceModelEx\ServiceBus\Discovery\ServiceBusDiscoveryClient.cs   26  134 ServiceModelEx

With only the Channel Reference:
Error   12  The type or namespace name 'TransportClientEndpointBehavior' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\rreukema\Downloads\Idesign_WCFDisk\AprilIDesignCD\Demos\ServiceBus\Explorer\PopulateSolution\ServiceBusHelper - Buffer.cs  21  78  PopulateNamespace

Answer (score 0):

Creating an application that supports both the lab and the production versions of Service Bus is going to be really hard, as there's no official backwards compatibility story between the two of them. (Labs is meant to be used to try out new features and get feedback from customers). What's the scenario you're trying to enable here?

As for the dll issues, are you referencing both versions of the assemblies on your project? If so, you'll hit versioning issues, specially if you have the ServiceBus dlls in the GAC. If you only want to target one version of the dlls at a time, I strongly suggest you use the full assembly name (version and everything) when adding a reference in your project. Another good idea is to add a reference not to the dll in the GAC, but the one of the install location, as it's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859333/azure-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-servicebus)