# 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, azureservicebus, servicebus

I get the following runtime erorr while spawning an azure worker job.

> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'

has anyone faced same issues?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859333/azure-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-servicebus) might help

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells us that the service bus assembly is missing when deployed your project. Please check your property of your assembly. Make sure that the value of `Copy Local` is `true` before deployment.

[image]

**Note**: The `Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll` needs to packaged with your project because it is **not available by default in Azure**.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely getting your .dll reference from your local computer.  From the GAC maybe, probably. Or hard coded to a long full-file-name-path.

You should consider using nuget to pull down your dependencies.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/3.4.0

This will allow your references to be in a relative path, and will work on your build-machine if/when you get one.

This below article will help you bridge the gap with Visual Studio and Nuget:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio

> Quickstart: Install and use a package in Visual Studio (Windows only)
>
> 07/23/2018 3 minutes to read
>            +1 NuGet packages contain reusable code that other developers make available to you for use in your projects. See What is NuGet? for
>   background. Packages are installed into a Visual Studio project using
>   the NuGet Package Manager or the Package Manager Console. This article
>   demonstrates the process using the popular Newtonsoft.Json package and
>   a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project. The same process
>   applies to any other .NET or .NET Core project.